# Update MySQL timestamp on condition

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table "ping_status"

```
CREATE TABLE `ping_status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ping_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `change_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

column `ts = time` when `ping_status` changes

How can i update column `ts` when only `ping_status` changes. There should no update in `ts` if change_status changes;

Comment: Did you resolve this? Are you looking for another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trigger`

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if NEW.ping_status<> OLD.ping_status Then

--Update ts here

end If

if NEW.change_status<> OLD.change_statusThen

update table1 set ts=old.ts where id=new.id

end If
END
```

Comment: ts will still get updated if change_status changes using this method as on update current_timestamp is still in place.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html), "if the column is auto-updated, it is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value". This means that when you update either ping_status or change_status, ts will be set to the current_timestamp. So, remove the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and explicitly update ts, when you update ping_status.

```
update ping_status set ping_status=some_value, ts=now() where id=some_value;
```

As you still have `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` any new values you insert will still get the current timestamp.

As as aside, it is probably best to avoid having common field and table names where possible.